# get specific data along with group by

Tags: mysql

I've a table named `log`.

**Table:**  [**log**](http://#)

```
ID    user_id    time_of_action
```

I want to get result for each user for each date `i.e.` `group by date,user_id`.

So, here's the expected output structure:

```
user_id     date    occurred_in_afternoon     occurred_at_night   total_action_count
```

**Explanation:**

**occurred_in_afternoon:** whether any action of a user occurred in between `12:00 PM` to `4:00 PM`

**occurred_at_night:** whether any action of a user occurred between `8:00 PM` to `12:00 AM` (next day)

**Schema and sample data:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `logs`;
CREATE TABLE `logs` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_of_action` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);


INSERT INTO `logs` VALUES ('1', '71', '2016-03-10 10:07:34');
INSERT INTO `logs` VALUES ('2', '66', '2016-03-10 14:07:57');
INSERT INTO `logs` VALUES ('3', '71', '2016-03-10 22:08:27');
INSERT INTO `logs` VALUES ('4', '71', '2016-03-10 15:08:40');
```

And here's my current query:

```
SELECT 
user_id,
DATE(time_of_action) `date`,
CASE WHEN time_of_action BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,12,DATE(time_of_action)) AND TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,16,DATE(time_of_action))  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END occurred_in_afternoon,
CASE WHEN time_of_action BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,20,DATE(time_of_action)) AND TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,24,DATE(time_of_action))  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END occurred_at_night,
COUNT(*) total_action_count
FROM `logs`
GROUP BY `date`,user_id
```

**my current output:**

```
user_id       date       occurred_in_afternoon       occurred_at_night    total_action_count
66           2016-03-10         1                       0                        1
71           2016-03-10         0                       0                        3
```

**Expected output:**

```
user_id       date       occurred_in_afternoon       occurred_at_night    total_action_count
66           2016-03-10         1                       0                        1
71           2016-03-10         1                       1                        3
```

The problem is that I am not getting the expected result. I guess occurred in afternoon value is reset by another time_of_action which doesn't lie in that afternoon region. 
And is it possible to implement it in a single query?

Comment: Try `GROUP BY DATE(time_of_action), user_id`

Comment: That's what I've tried.@PaulSpiegel

Comment: Sorry, that does not matter. You are missing `SUM()`.. Try `SUM(CASE ... END)`

Comment: why do I need `sum`? I don't think `SUM` can do anything here. @PaulSpiegel

Comment: @AnonymousOne every column in the query with group by has to be either making the group or be used within an aggregate / window function.

Comment: Yes you are right. So what could I do in this case to get the desired output?@ConsiderMe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to use an aggregate function. You can use `MAX()` or `BIT_OR()` for your purpose:

```
SELECT 
user_id,
DATE(time_of_action) `date`,
MAX(CASE WHEN time_of_action BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,12,DATE(time_of_action)) AND TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,16,DATE(time_of_action))  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) occurred_in_afternoon,
MAX(CASE WHEN time_of_action BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,20,DATE(time_of_action)) AND TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,24,DATE(time_of_action))  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) occurred_at_night,
COUNT(*) total_action_count
FROM `logs`
GROUP BY `date`,user_id
```

**Update:** I would also prefer a more readable version like

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    DATE(time_of_action) `date`,
    BIT_OR(TIME(time_of_action) BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '16:00:00') occurred_in_afternoon,
    BIT_OR(TIME(time_of_action) BETWEEN '20:00:00' AND '23:59:59') occurred_at_night,
    COUNT(*) total_action_count
FROM `logs`
GROUP BY `date`,user_id
```

Comment: `Sum` might give me output greater than one in some cases. I want `Binary` value for those two fields. @PaulSpiegel

Comment: It's allways 1 or 0?

Comment: combine it with SIGN() :-)

Comment: Look I've added an answer too making an alias of the table. But I liked the `SIGN()` function.

Comment: Better to use BIT_AND() or MAX()

Comment: `BIT_AND`  doesn't work in this case. `SIGN()` works. Rollback your answer.

Comment: Both - BIT_AND and MAX work for me. You have to use it without SUM

Comment: where to use `MAX`? Please show the complete change in your query

Comment: Sorry `BIT_AND()` will ofcourse not work. Use `MAX()` :-) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46fb04/1

Comment: `MAX()` OR `SIGN()` both should work, right? @PaulSpiegel

Comment: Yes. MAX(), SIGN(SUM()) or BIT_OR().

Comment: Thanks for `MAX()`, `SIGN()` and `BIT_OR()`

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking to have an alias of the result table that I've got through `SUM` in order to get `Binary value` for those two fields.

```
SELECT 
t.user_id,
t.date,
CASE WHEN t.occurred_in_afternoon > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS occurred_in_afternoon,
CASE WHEN t.occurred_at_night > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS occurred_at_night,
t.total_action_count
FROM 
(SELECT 
user_id,
DATE(time_of_action) `date`,
SUM(CASE WHEN time_of_action BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,12,DATE(time_of_action)) AND TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,16,DATE(time_of_action))  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) occurred_in_afternoon,
SUM(CASE WHEN time_of_action BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,20,DATE(time_of_action)) AND TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR,24,DATE(time_of_action))  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) occurred_at_night,
COUNT(*) total_action_count
FROM `logs`
GROUP BY `date`,user_id) t
```